# Remove all substrings in first-array that match elements in second-array

Tags: arrays, clojure

**The Quest**

Remove every substring in **first-array** for every string in **second-array** that matches.

What is the best way to do it in Clojure?

> Example:
>
> **first-array:** ["Adam" "Goolan" "silly"]
>
> **second-array:** [ "a" "oo" "ll"]
>
> **result:** ["Adm" "Gln" "siy"]
>
> Note that the result should be the same if
>
> **second-array:** [ "oo" "ll" "a"]

Comment: Is this any element in the first array that matches any in the second or only if it matches its specific index? I.e. would the result be the same if the second array were `["oo" "ll" "a"]`?

Comment: every string as a whole

Comment: Sorry, was standing in the door. Yes the result would be the same!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is by matched elements (i.e. first item in first matches first item in second and so on):

```
> (defn the-quest [xs ys] 
    (map #(clojure.string/replace (first %1) (second %1) "") (map vector xs ys)))
#'sandbox1427/the-quest
> (the-quest ["Adam" "Goolan" "silly"] ["a" "oo" "ll"])
("Adm" "Glan" "siy")
```

See @Lee's comment below:

```
> (map #(clojure.string/replace %1 %2 "") ["Adam" "Goolan" "silly"] ["a" "oo" "ll"])
("Adm" "Glan" "siy")
>
```

Note - the above courtesy of http://www.tryclj.com/

With any-to-any matching:

```
user=> (defn repl-all [x ys] 
  #_=>    (reduce #(clojure.string/replace %1 %2 "") x ys))

user=> (defn the-quest [xs ys]
  #_=>    (map #(repl-all %1 ys) xs))

user=> (the-quest ["Adam" "Goolan" "silly"] ["a" "oo" "ll"])
("Adm" "Gln" "siy")
```

Comment: `map` can take any number of source collections so you don't need to create an intermediate vector i.e `(map #(string/replace %1 %2 "") xs ys))`

Comment: It needs to apply to every element. As in example: ("Adm" "Gln" "siy") not ("Adm" "Glan" "siy")

Answer (score 1):

There's two slightly different formulations of the problem and your example doesn't quite indicate which you want:

1. Make one pass, removing any substring of the input strings which matches any of the second strings.
2. Make one pass for each string to remove in sequence. This can remove more characters than option 1, as each removal can create new substrings which otherwise wouldn't qualify.

If what you want is the second case, that seems to be taken care of. If it's the first case, I'd suggest something like

```
(import java.util.regex.Pattern)

(defn the-quest [strs to-remove]
  (let[my-pattern (->> to-remove
                       (map #(Pattern/quote %))
                       (clojure.string/join "|")
                       re-pattern)]
    (map #(clojure.string/replace % my-pattern "") strs)))
```

Here I just create a regular expression matching any of the `to-remove` strings and do one `replace` on instances of the regex. You have to bring in `Pattern/quote` if you want to be able to use regex control characters in the to-removes.